# I want to update my website cache on user browser on regular basis

Tags: php, browser-cache

Every time i update my javascript and css files on my website the user have to clear his/her browsing history , cache etc from its browser so i want to update my cache on user browser on regular basis

Comment: Whats setting the headers? Maybe look into using a service worker.

Comment: Depending of the technique you use, there is mostly a way to make sure your assets won't be cached during development. Please give more information. What browser, what do you use to develop your site? (Framework/webserver, the full stack pls)

Comment: Do you only want a solution for the JS and CSS files caching in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to resolve this problem is to add a version string to the end of the script file request.

For example when you got:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Change it to:

```
<script src="myscripts.js?v=999"></script>
```

Or a unix timestamp:

```
<script src="myscripts.js?dt=:unix_timestamp:"></script>
```

Works the same way with `css` files.

---

You can also add a header entry to your `HTML` code (`head` section):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content=":value:">
```

The `value` can be:

- `Public` - may be cached in public shared caches.
- `Private` - may only be cached in private cache
- `No-Cache` - may not be cached
- `No-Store` - may be cached but not archived

---

You can also do the above in `HTTP` response headers.

For example:

```
Cache-control: no-cache
```

Or set a cache lifespan in seconds

```
Cache-control: max-age=60
```